# How to update field values in Odoo 17 using a parent component using JS

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-17, odoo-owl

I am using Odoo 17 right now, and to update a field value in my version 16 codebase, I used this line:

`if (component.props.type === "many2one") { component.props.update([]); }`

I discovered that this syntax is no longer valid after migrating to Odoo 17, so if you could kindly advise me on the other way to update field values in Odoo 17?

Answer (score 2):

The props `update` was removed in [[REF] web, * : simplify concrete fields API - remove update prop](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/8cde3e84bb70a2bd097921c08c0059bf65bee602) commit

> In this commit we will remove `update` prop from concrete fields. Now each
> field will directly use `this.props.record.update` to make changes, and
> handle the save in fields that need to (e.g. priority). As a consequence
> of this, the record props need to be mandatory.

***Example:***

```
await component.props.update(val);
```

Was changed to:

```
await component.props.record.update({ [component.props.name]: val });
```